# How to change a variable from an activity inside my adapter (java class change variable passed to it)

Tags: java, android

My Activity has the value `Sound selectedToe`. I want my `soundPageChangeListener` to be able to update the `selectedToe` of the activity, so I pass `selectedToe` like this:

```
SoundPageChangeListener soundPageChangeListener = new SoundPageChangeListener(soundsToe, selectedToe);
```

however, when I change `selectedToe` inside `soundPageChangeListener`:

```
public class SoundPageChangeListener implements ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener {

    private ArrayList<Sound> sounds;
    Sound currentSound;

    public SoundPageChangeListener(ArrayList<Sound> sounds, Sound currentSound) {
        this.sounds = sounds;
        this.currentSound = currentSound;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        Sound sound = sounds.get(position);
        currentSound = sound;
    }
```

the `selectedToe` on the activity still `null`.

**Aren't all java values pointers? If I change something inside the listener, shouldn't it change outside?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make `SoundPageChangeListener` inner class of your activity, so the Listener can access to the Activity `selectedToe` variable. 
Having an inner class will allow this class `SoundPageChangeListener` to have visibility and access to your activity `selectedToe` variable.

The pointer is not kept in your scenario as you are creating a new class instance. Your are assigning `currentSound` not re-pointing to the memory address.

Then in `onPageSelected` assign `selectedToe` with `sound`

```java
class YourActivity {
    ...
    Sound selectedToe = currentSound // set the default sound if any

    // Inside the activity, declare your listener
    public class SoundPageChangeListener implements ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener {

        private ArrayList<Sound> sounds;

        // only the sound list is required here
        public SoundPageChangeListener(ArrayList<Sound> sounds) {
            this.sounds = sounds;
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            Sound sound = sounds.get(position);
            YourActivity.this.selectedToe = sound
        }
    }
}
```